# Flutter - Child widget with HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer in CustomScrollview

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a child widget in CustomScrollView(which is vertical scroll). I add a child Widget in this  CustomScrollView. This child widget only add a HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer. When I vertical drag this child widget, CutomScrollView will scrollView. How to avoid CustomScollview scroll when  I interact with the child widget?

Comment: Please make your question `clearer`. We don't understand anything. I don't really get what you're saying that much but I think changing CustomScrollView to SingleChildScrollView will solve your problem.

Comment: @Uni , I put a slider on a CustomScollView, When I drag the slider, the scrollview will scroll up and down slightly, so my question is When I drag the slider, how to fibidden scroll of the scrollview?

Comment: @Uni https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759601/flutter-how-to-prevent-scrollview-scroll-when-i-drag-a-slider-on-it